# cventry using moderncv class

Tags: errors, moderncv

I am quite new in LaTeX.
Actually, I want to use cventry using moderncv class.

I faced with lots of errors while I am using multiple `\cventry`.

```
\section{Experience}

\subsection{Vocational}

\cventry{2009--2012}{Supervisor}{\textsc{Technical and Vocational Training organization 
(TVTO)}}{East Azarbaijan Branch, Iran}{}{Supervision of, Teaching Standards.}
\subsection{Civil engineering, Surveying and Architecture}
%------------------------------------------------

\cventry{2009--2012}{Writer}{\textsc{Technical and Vocational Training organization 
(TVTO)}}{Tehran, Iran}{}{Writing, Teaching Standards, in Geomatics.}

%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Autodesk Civil design, Autodesk survey, Civil 3D, Road surveyor, Construction surveyor, Surveying with single channel GPS}

\cventry{2008--2010}{Lecturer}{Borj Azar Co.}{East Azarbaijan, Iran}{}{Training Surveying Instruments & digital Mapping.}  

\cventry{2008--2009}{Lecturer}{Klick Now}{East Azarbaijan, Iran}{}{Training Audesk Land Desktop.}  

\cventry{2008--2009}{Surveyor}{Borj Azar Co.}{East Azarbaijan, Iran}{}{Surveying of water and watershed management, drainage channals and irrigation water piping, Akhola project.}  

\cventry{2007--2008}{Surveyor}{Borj Azar Co.}{East Azarbaijan, Iran}{}{Surveying of Daryan Dam.}  

\cventry{2006--2007}{Surveyor and Cartograph}{Borj Azar Co.}{East Azarbaijan, Iran}{}{Surveying and cadastral mapping of Shabster.}
```

Could you explain me how I can use multiple `\ceventry` in context successively.

Comment: Sth interesting, I found out, the errors almost (101) occqured because of this line:            \cventry{2008--2010}{Lecturer}{Borj Azar Co.}{East Azarbaijan, Iran}{}{Training Surveying Instruments & digital Mapping.}

Comment: Put `\ before &`

Comment: @hpesoj626 where should I put it?

Comment: The line you commented on should be: `\cventry{2008--2010}{Lecturer}{Borj Azar Co.}{East Azarbaijan, Iran}{}{Training Surveying Instruments \& digital Mapping.}` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included some parts of the code to make the file compile. In future posts, it pays to have a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for members of the **TeX.SX** community to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

This should work.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}%
\recomputelengths
\firstname{John}%
\familyname{Doe}%
\address{Here}{Somewhere}%
\phone{+1 234 567 890}% 
\email{john [at] mailmail.com}%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Experience}

\subsection{Vocational}

\cventry{2008--2010}{Lecturer}{Borj Azar Co.}{East Azarbaijan, Iran}{}{Training Surveying Instruments \& digital Mapping.}  

\end{document}
```

Rember that `&` is a special character in TeX. To use it, you have to put a backslash before it.